# Rails 7 and Import-map and loading custom JS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I am trying to load my custom js. but getting errors.

Error is following.

Failed to register controller: notification (controllers/notification_controller) Error: Unable to resolve specifier '@noty' imported from http://localhost:3000/assets/controllers/notification_contr...

```
│   ├── javascript
│   │   ├── application.js
│   │   ├── controllers
│   │   │   ├── application.js
│   │   │   ├── index.js
│   │   │   ├── notification_controller.js
│   │   └── lib
│   │       └── noty.js
```

### notification_controller.js

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import Noty from "@noty"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ 'type', 'message' ]

  ....// some codes.

}
```

### config/importmap.rb

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"

## lib
pin "@noty", to: "app/javascript/lib/noty.js", preload: true
```

What did I do wrong? also some other questions I have is, where "stimulus.min.js" and "turbo.min.js" file exist?

Answer (score 10):

Your error is because you need to fix the path

`pin "@noty", to: "app/javascript/lib/noty.js", preload: true`

to

`pin "@noty", to: "lib/noty.js", preload: true`

However, you are going to run into more problems importing `Noty` because of how the library exports modules. The easiest way to add the library is through the asset pipeline.

To do this

1. Add `noty.js` to `app/assets/config`
2. Add `noty.css` to `app/assets/stylesheets`
3. Add `//= link noty.js` to `app/assets/config/manifest.js`
4. Add this to `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "noty" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "noty" %>
```

Once this is done, `Noty` should be available in your js controllers. e.g.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [ 'type', 'message' ]

  test(){
    var noty = new Noty({text: 'Hi!'});
    noty.show();
  }
}
```

Comment: `pin "@noty", to: "lib/noty.js", preload: true` does not work for me. The browser keeps telling `Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`.

Comment: @RobertReiz that browser console error message is known to the rails dev group, expected and of no further consquence.  bit of a red herring...